# Show the appointed/elected date for moderators on ALL Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, moderators

Why doesn't the https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators page have the elected/appointed date for moderators on **all** sites?

I see that (to name a few):

- Christianity does display the date
- Islam does not
- Stack Overflow does
- WordPress Development does
- Joomla does not

After clicking through a few, there seems to be a correlation between beta sites not displaying the dates and "full member" (graduated/non-beta) sites displaying the dates.

Assuming that site status is the distinction, why bother making this distinction?  Why not show the appointed/elected dates for all moderators regardless of the site's status?  It seems strange to me.

**Edit to pivot my question as a feature request:**

Ultimately, my stance is: don't deny the public being able to see the start date of a moderator (regardless of how they got the gig).  If I wanted to talk to the most-senior or most-junior moderator in a particular community, then the show details section could swiftly reveal that information.

Unless there is a compelling reason to keep the appointed moderators' start dates secret, please amend the page.

Comment: It seems indeed based on site status. Some betas now have pro-tempore elections, and even for elected moderators (e.g. me on Chess.SE) the elected date isn't shown.

Comment: Also, for graduated sites the mods are listed in order by election date, while on betas it appears to be random (not in order of appointment).

Answer (score 11):

You don't see dates because those moderators *were never elected*. All of the cases where there is no date involves moderators that were asked by the Community Managers team to act as [*Moderator Pro-Tempore*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/) instead.

This applies to [all Islam moderators](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) for example, but also to the [Meta.SE moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). These are sites that just don't have any moderators that gained the status through an election.

There are also sites where there is a *mix* of appointed and elected moderators, and there it is easier to see the difference. [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) is one such site:

[image: Screenshot of the Community Building section of the moderators overview, showing 3 moderators, where the first moderator listed as an 'elected 2019' column showing with a hand-drawn red circle to draw attention to that part. The other 2 moderator names do not have such a column.]

Other such sites are [Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=moderators), [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), [Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)

Finally, there are also 3 *appointed* moderators. One of these was nominated in an ad-hoc process on their site meta before there was a way to run elections ([random](https://superuser.com/users/307/random) on Super User, [appointed March 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/26/moderator-changes-on-super-user/) after being [nominated on the Super User Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/895/should-random-be-elected-a-moderator-on-super-user)), or were called up to meet additional demand after an election ([Michael Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13531/michael-myers) on Stack Overflow, [appointed July 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/11/summer-2010-moderator-appointments/) after running in the [manually run 2010 election](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/02/09/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-results/), and [waiwai933](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/100/waiwai933) on English Language & Usage, [July 2011](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/another-community-moderator)). The process of how additional moderators are recorded has since changed; e.g. [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) was [called up after an election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296975/100297) but his moderatorship is recorded against the original [2015 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6); this is now the norm.

Comment: So what is the risk of showing, for example, "_appointed 2015_"?  Why bother to withhold information pertaining to the length of service?  I can't imagine that anyone interested in the "moderators' details" will ever think to themselves, "Geez, this moderator was merely _appointed_? ...I could do without the date they started -- what a total waste of pixels."  Do I need to retag/rephase my question to convert this into a feature request?

Comment: @mickmackusa they are not appointed, though. Pro-tempore moderators are expected to be moderators for a limited time, while elected and appointed moderators are given a diamond “for life”. Not sure what a good label would be for them nor what that would link to.

Comment: On Joomla Stack Exchange, I was appointed as a moderator because I was an uncontested candidate.  Since then we finally had a fruitful election with 4 candidates, after which Harald was crowned a mod for a second time (after previously being one of the initial Moderator Pro-Tempore moderators, then stepping down).  Pe7er was recently elected as a mod for the first time.  None of us have a date next to our names, but this feature seems like a relevant detail to list for all communities.